# Is it possible to create PDF with Generic CUPS-PDF Printer to stdout, no to file?

Tags: pdf, cups, stdout

I know that Generic CUPS-PDF Printer can read bytes from stdin.

For example, so:

```
cmd = ["lp", "-d", "PDF", "-stdin"]
process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate(self.outgoing_bytes)
```

Is it possible to create PDF with Generic CUPS-PDF Printer to stdout, no to file?

(I want convert files to pdf via CUPS)

Comment: I'm trying to understand. Why do you want to avoid saving it as a file? (You could always send the file to stdout after creating it.) What exactly are you hoping to "convert"? The input file to `lp` is typically already a pdf. As far as I know, the only other file types it accepts are plain text and ps, but those can be easily converted to PDFs in other ways. (E.g., ghostscript, which is required for cups-pdf, provides ps2pdf which can pipe to stdout.)

Comment: I don't want save file cause I write a class with converting .odt to .pdf in one of its methods. Input file for `lp` is not .pdf only. In my case is .odt and cups save it to pdf file successfully.
Anyway thank you for answer and advice.

Comment: If I try to print an odt file with lp I get the error message "lp: Unsupported document-format "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"". As far as I understand things, when a program like LibreOffice prints an .odt file it converts it to .pdf or postscript before submitting the print job. You can convert odt to pdf headlessly with libreoffice.  `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.odt`.

Comment: yeap, I tried it but in this case libreoffice can't work with stdin and stdout. I also tried `unoconv`. It work great! But I can't run it in docker. I've been trying for a few days now, but to no avail. So I started to look for another ways to convert .odt to .pdf

Comment: If you're interesting about my problem in docker [here link to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73816817/unoconv-error-cannot-import-name-element-from-base)

Comment: I solved the problem. I looked at her wider:)
.ott template (and accordingly .odt file) was not a mandatory requirement.
I replace .ott (and .odt) to .html. Now I fill in html template with jinja2 and and do everything I need with it!
@frabjous Thank you for discussion!